# How to compare each element separately of two char lists Standard ML

Tags: sml

I am very new to SML and i am trying to write a function where it compares two char lists, in a way that it takes one character from list1 and compares it with all the characters from list2, for example

```
val list1 = explode("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
val list2 = explode("bcdaghklfeijonmtrqpsvuwyzx!-232=,./;'[]{}:?<")
```

so from list1 it takes the element 'a', and then compares it with each element of list2 and it keeps checking all elements, if the jumbled list2 is equal to to the non jumbled list1 then it returns true

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/),

> The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem. This leads to enormous amounts of wasted time and energy, both on the part of people asking for help, and on the part of those providing help.

Are you testing if `list1` is a subset, sub-multiset, sub-string, sub-sequence, or a permutation of `list2`? Or if they are set-equivalent? Try and express your actual problem and *then* describe your attempted solution. :-)

You probably want to use a combination of `List.exists` and `List.all`.

For example, if you were to test if `list1` is a subset of `list2`:

```
fun contains (ys, x) = List.exists (fn y => x = y) ys
fun isSubsetOf (xs, ys) = List.all (fn x => contains (ys, x)) xs
```

Which says: For all `x` ∈ `xs`, there must exist a `y` ∈ `ys` such that `x` = `y`.

Comment: Nice explanation, though I suspect that this is homework and that OP's instructor is expecting a naïve solution that doesn't use standard library higher-order functions. It is hard to know for sure until they clarify a bit more.

Comment: it doesnt matter how we accomplish it, it is supposed to be written in 2 different programming languages it didnt take me long to do it in other ones but standard ml is literally new to me, anyways the problem states that we are supposed to detect a pangram sentence so list1 will contain the sentence and list2 will contain the alphabets from a through z and if all the alphabets are in the sentence in list 1 then its a pangram else not